# Can some one help me to establish the following isomorphism .

Tags: group-theory

$$U(2^n)= Z_2\bigoplus Z_{2^{n-2}}$$ I can figure out that orders of both are same since $\phi(2^n)=2^{n-1}$ . Cannot proceed any further .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* One nice proof, outlined in Dummitt & Foote, goes as follows:

1. Show that if $n\ge 3$ then use the binomial theorem to show that $(1+2^2)^{2^{n-2}}\equiv 1\mod{2^n}$ but that $(1+2^2)^{2^{n-2}}\not\equiv 1\mod{2^n}$, and conclude that $5$ has order $2^{n-2}$ in $U_{2^n}$.
2. Show that $U_{2^n}$ is not cyclic for $n\ge 3$ by finding two distinct subgroups of order $2$.
3. Conclude that $U_{2^n}$ is as you claimed.

Comment: Thank you , that helped !!